# Background colour cutting off in automatic height div

Tags: html, css, wordpress, height, width

I have a problem, only about 100px of background colour is showing. I want the background colour to flow with the text. I dont have a set height for the div as I am developing this for a wordpress theme and I want the user to be able to put in as much content as possible without being restricted. Any help guys? Thanks In advance

HTML

```
<div class="maincontentinnercon">


            <div class="titlecon"><h1>About Us</h1></div>

            <div class="pcontent">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ut felis at lacus tempor commodo. Duis at massa eget orci pellentesque vehicula in eu orci. Fusce suscipit mauris non odio mollis condimentum. Phasellus sodales sapien quis ultricies eleifend. In velit lacus, elementum sit amet feugiat sed, molestie ac justo. Proin sit amet pretium est, eu vulputate justo. Donec facilisis velit sed mi mollis malesuada. Curabitur tincidunt libero elit, at lacinia velit suscipit sed. Maecenas posuere placerat ante eu cursus. Maecenas facilisis, mauris nec hendrerit laoreet, leo mi placerat enim, in condimentum ipsum dolor ac lorem. Maecenas vestibulum lacinia vulputate. Phasellus eget metus mi. Fusce quis sollicitudin lectus, sit amet ullamcorper purus. Suspendisse dictum ante ac arcu dignissim, vel ultricies nisl gravida. Sed dapibus mauris cursus pellentesque pretium. Vivamus imperdiet fringilla laoreet.<br/><br/>

In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Morbi congue dui posuere, venenatis nunc in, laoreet leo. Sed sodales nisl quis dictum vulputate. Ut vel lorem ac arcu rhoncus auctor. Fusce elit enim, auctor at ultricies nec, blandit quis mauris. Morbi fermentum, est eu tempus rhoncus, orci nulla lobortis magna, euismod lobortis urna odio vel quam. Aliquam fermentum, nisi at adipiscing tristique, eros sapien malesuada quam, at venenatis eros turpis quis dui. Integer massa justo, vestibulum eu pharetra viverra, eleifend nec elit. In sollicitudin varius suscipit. Phasellus ac lectus in ante fringilla consectetur pellentesque vitae lectus. Sed quis magna condimentum, scelerisque turpis id, auctor arcu. Maecenas mattis magna augue, vitae faucibus nisl interdum ut. Ut sed augue vitae nibh suscipit tempor sed sed turpis. Nunc dictum eu nisi malesuada consequat. <br/><br/>
elit. Maecenas ut felis at lacus tempor commodo. Duis at massa eget orci pellentesque vehicula in eu orci. Fusce suscipit mauris non odio mollis condimentum. Phasellus sodales sapien quis ultricies eleifend. In velit lacus, elementum sit amet feugiat sed, molestie ac justo. Proin sit amet pretium est, eu vulputate justo. Donec facilisis velit sed mi mollis malesuada. Curabitur tincidunt libero elit, at lacinia velit suscipit sed. Maecenas posuere placerat ante eu cursus. Maecenas facilisis, mauris nec hendrerit laoreet, leo mi placerat enim, in condimentum ipsum dolor ac lorem. Maecenas vestibulum lacinia vulputate. Phasellus eget metus mi. Fusce quis sollicitudin lectus, sit amet ullamcorper purus. Suspendisse dictum ante ac arcu dignissim, vel ultricies nisl gravida. Sed dapibus mauris cursus pellentesque pretium. Vivamus imperdiet fringilla laoreet.<br/><br/>

In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Morbi congue dui posuere, venenatis nunc in, laoreet leo. Sed sodales nisl quis dictum vulputate. Ut vel lorem ac arcu rhoncus auctor. Fusce elit enim, auctor at ultricies nec, blandit quis mauris. Morbi fermentum, est eu tempus rhoncus, orci nulla lobortis magna, euismod lobortis urna odio vel quam. Aliquam fermentum, nisi at adipiscing tristique, eros sapien malesuada quam, at venenatis eros turpis quis dui. Integer massa justo, vestibulum eu pharetra viverra, eleifend nec elit. In sollicitudin varius suscipit. Phasellus ac lectus in ante fringilla consectetur pellentesque vitae lectus. Sed quis magna condimentum, scelerisque turpis id, auctor arcu. Maecenas mattis magna augue, vitae faucibus nisl interdum ut. Ut sed augue vitae nibh suscipit tempor sed sed turpis. Nunc dictum eu nisi malesuada consequat. <br/><br/>
elit. Maecenas ut felis at lacus tempor commodo. Duis at massa eget orci pellentesque vehicula in eu orci. Fusce suscipit mauris non odio mollis condimentum. Phasellus sodales sapien quis ultricies eleifend. In velit lacus, elementum sit amet feugiat sed, molestie ac justo. Proin sit amet pretium est, eu vulputate justo. Donec facilisis velit sed mi mollis malesuada. Curabitur tincidunt libero elit, at lacinia velit suscipit sed. Maecenas posuere placerat ante eu cursus. Maecenas facilisis, mauris nec hendrerit laoreet, leo mi placerat enim, in condimentum ipsum dolor ac lorem. Maecenas vestibulum lacinia vulputate. Phasellus eget metus mi. Fusce quis sollicitudin lectus, sit amet ullamcorper purus. Suspendisse dictum ante ac arcu dignissim, vel ultricies nisl gravida. Sed dapibus mauris cursus pellentesque pretium. Vivamus imperdiet fringilla laoreet.<br/><br/>

In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Morbi congue dui posuere, venenatis nunc in, laoreet leo. Sed sodales nisl quis dictum vulputate. Ut vel lorem ac arcu rhoncus auctor. Fusce elit enim, auctor at ultricies nec, blandit quis mauris. Morbi fermentum, est eu tempus rhoncus, orci nulla lobortis magna, euismod lobortis urna odio vel quam. Aliquam fermentum, nisi at adipiscing tristique, eros sapien malesuada quam, at venenatis eros turpis quis dui. Integer massa justo, vestibulum eu pharetra viverra, eleifend nec elit. In sollicitudin varius suscipit. Phasellus ac lectus in ante fringilla consectetur pellentesque vitae lectus. Sed quis magna condimentum, scelerisque turpis id, auctor arcu. Maecenas mattis magna augue, vitae faucibus nisl interdum ut. Ut sed augue vitae nibh suscipit tempor sed sed turpis. Nunc dictum eu nisi malesuada consequat. <br/><br/>
elit. Maecenas ut felis at lacus tempor commodo. Duis at massa eget orci pellentesque vehicula in eu orci. Fusce suscipit mauris non odio mollis condimentum. Phasellus sodales sapien quis ultricies eleifend. In velit lacus, elementum sit amet feugiat sed, molestie ac justo. Proin sit amet pretium est, eu vulputate justo. Donec facilisis velit sed mi mollis malesuada. Curabitur tincidunt libero elit, at lacinia velit suscipit sed. Maecenas posuere placerat ante eu cursus. Maecenas facilisis, mauris nec hendrerit laoreet, leo mi placerat enim, in condimentum ipsum dolor ac lorem. Maecenas vestibulum lacinia vulputate. Phasellus eget metus mi. Fusce quis sollicitudin lectus, sit amet ullamcorper purus. Suspendisse dictum ante ac arcu dignissim, vel ultricies nisl gravida. Sed dapibus mauris cursus pellentesque pretium. Vivamus imperdiet fringilla laoreet.<br/><br/>

In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Morbi congue dui posuere, venenatis nunc in, laoreet leo. Sed sodales nisl quis dictum vulputate. Ut vel lorem ac arcu rhoncus auctor. Fusce elit enim, auctor at ultricies nec, blandit quis mauris. Morbi fermentum, est eu tempus rhoncus, orci nulla lobortis magna, euismod lobortis urna odio vel quam. Aliquam fermentum, nisi at adipiscing tristique, eros sapien malesuada quam, at venenatis eros turpis quis dui. Integer massa justo, vestibulum eu pharetra viverra, eleifend nec elit. In sollicitudin varius suscipit. Phasellus ac lectus in ante fringilla consectetur pellentesque vitae lectus. Sed quis magna condimentum, scelerisque turpis id, auctor arcu. Maecenas mattis magna augue, vitae faucibus nisl interdum ut. Ut sed augue vitae nibh suscipit tempor sed sed turpis. Nunc dictum eu nisi malesuada consequat. <br/><br/>
elit. Maecenas ut felis at lacus tempor commodo. Duis at massa eget orci pellentesque vehicula in eu orci. Fusce suscipit mauris non odio mollis condimentum. Phasellus sodales sapien quis ultricies eleifend. In velit lacus, elementum sit amet feugiat sed, molestie ac justo. Proin sit amet pretium est, eu vulputate justo. Donec facilisis velit sed mi mollis malesuada. Curabitur tincidunt libero elit, at lacinia velit suscipit sed. Maecenas posuere placerat ante eu cursus. Maecenas facilisis, mauris nec hendrerit laoreet, leo mi placerat enim, in condimentum ipsum dolor ac lorem. Maecenas vestibulum lacinia vulputate. Phasellus eget metus mi. Fusce quis sollicitudin lectus, sit amet ullamcorper purus. Suspendisse dictum ante ac arcu dignissim, vel ultricies nisl gravida. Sed dapibus mauris cursus pellentesque pretium. Vivamus imperdiet fringilla laoreet.<br/><br/>

In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Morbi congue dui posuere, venenatis nunc in, laoreet leo. Sed sodales nisl quis dictum vulputate. Ut vel lorem ac arcu rhoncus auctor. Fusce elit enim, auctor at ultricies nec, blandit quis mauris. Morbi fermentum, est eu tempus rhoncus, orci nulla lobortis magna, euismod lobortis urna odio vel quam. Aliquam fermentum, nisi at adipiscing tristique, eros sapien malesuada quam, at venenatis eros turpis quis dui. Integer massa justo, vestibulum eu pharetra viverra, eleifend nec elit. In sollicitudin varius suscipit. Phasellus ac lectus in ante fringilla consectetur pellentesque vitae lectus. Sed quis magna condimentum, scelerisque turpis id, auctor arcu. Maecenas mattis magna augue, vitae faucibus nisl interdum ut. Ut sed augue vitae nibh suscipit tempor sed sed turpis. Nunc dictum eu nisi malesuada consequat. <br/><br/>

</div>



        </div>
```

CSS

```
.maincontentinnercon {
    margin:0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 990px;
    height:auto;
    background-color: #000;
    padding-top:40px;
    padding-bottom:40px;
    padding-left:43px;
    padding-right:43px;
}

.titlecon {
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    width: 990px;
    height:47px;
    margin-bottom:13px;
}

.pcontent {
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    width: 990px;
    height:auto;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `display:table;` and `color:#fff;`

```
.maincontentinnercon {
    margin:0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 990px;
    height:auto;
    background-color: #000;
    padding-top:40px;
    padding-bottom:40px;
    padding-left:43px;
    padding-right:43px;
    display:table;
    color:#fff;
}
```

Here is the JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/4T2CB/

Comment: Enjoy that, but you have removed the mark of my answer, as the best answer, consider vote up too.

Answer (score 1):

Just add float:left;

```
.maincontentinnercon {
  margin:0 auto;
  position: relative;
  float:left;
  width: 990px;
  height:auto;
  background-color: #000;
  padding-top:40px;
  padding-bottom:40px;
  padding-left:43px;
  padding-right:43px;
}
```

Because all your other elements are floating

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/x6gZt/)

Answer (score 0):

The elements have a float.

Probably the solution is to give them overflow: hidden or a clear: both;

Can you make a fiddle so I can see it?